# Running customs rules for particular target

Tags: android, ant

I'm an ANT noob so struggling to find online where I can solve this little riddle for my android project.

What I would like to do is run some rules depending on what ant command I run.
Basically when I run ANT DEBUG, I don't want any of the custom rules running.
And when I run ANT RELEASE I want my custom rules to run.

At the moment my custom rules run no matter what at the pre build stage.

Here is my build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="MainActivity" default="help">
<property file="local.properties" />
<property file="ant.properties" />
<property environment="env" />

<condition property="sdk.dir" value="${env.ANDROID_HOME}">
    <isset property="env.ANDROID_HOME" />
</condition>

<loadproperties srcFile="project.properties" />
<fail
        message="sdk.dir is missing. Make sure to generate local.properties using 'android update project' or to inject it through the ANDROID_HOME environment variable."
        unless="sdk.dir"
/>

<import file="custom_rules.xml" optional="true" />

<import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml" />
```

Here is my custom_rules.xml

```
<project>
<macrodef name="git" description="run a git command">
    <attribute name="command" />
    <attribute name="dir" default="" />
    <element name="args" optional="true" />
    <element name="gitOutputRedirector" optional="true"/>
    <sequential>
        <echo message="git @{command}" />
        <exec executable="git" dir="@{dir}">
            <arg value="@{command}" />
            <args/>
            <gitOutputRedirector/>
        </exec>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>

<target name="-pre-build" depends="set-version-using-file,git-last-commit-hash-rev-parse" >

</target>

<target name="set-version-using-file">
    <!-- Load properties from "version.properties" file -->     
    <property file="version.properties" />
    <replaceregexp file="AndroidManifest.xml" match="android:versionCode(.*)"
                           replace='android:versionCode="${Version.Code}"'/>
    <replaceregexp file="AndroidManifest.xml" match='android:versionName="\d+\.+\d+\.+\d+\.+\d"'
                           replace='android:versionName="${Version.Name}"'/>        
   <echo message="Set android:versionCode as ${Version.Code}" />
   <echo message="Set android:versionName as ${Version.Name}" />
</target>


<!-- Get the last commit -->
<target name="git-last-commit-hash-rev-parse" description="Commits all changes to version git" >
    <property file="version.properties" />
    <git command="rev-parse" >
        <args>
            <arg value="HEAD" />
        </args>
        <gitOutputRedirector>
            <redirector outputproperty="git.last.commit"/>
         </gitOutputRedirector>
    </git>
    <echo message="Last commit found was ${git.last.commit}" />
    <echo message="Will now tag ${git.last.commit} with ${Version.Name}" />

    <git command="tag">
        <args>
            <!-- This tags the last commit with the full version name -->
            <arg value="${Version.Name}" />
            <!-- For some reason why it doesn't like this command through ant.-->
            <!-- <arg value="${Version.Name} ${git.last.commit} -m 'Tagged for build'" /> -->
        </args>
    </git>

</target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've solved it!

I moved my macro def and two targets into the main build.xml

and in my main build.xml I added the following

```
<target name="releaseCan" depends="set-version-using-file, release, git-last-commit-hash-rev-parse"/>
```

Changed the version target to the following so it runs pre-build

```
<target name="set-version-using-file" depends="-pre-build">
```

Changed the git target to the following, so  it runs post build.

```
<target name="git-last-commit-hash-rev-parse" description="Commits all changes to version git" depends="-post-build">
```

So I run ant releaseCan it does the following

Modify the AndroidManifest.xml (-pre-build)
Run the normal release target (where it does the compiling and signing etc etc)
Run the git commands (-post-build)

So its fairly basic, I'm not sure if the post-build will still run if the release target fails.